# Returning values from XML file with $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

Just trying to read an `XML` file using a `Jquery` `ajax` function and then using a callback function, store the text in the `URLS` var

It isn't working, so here is the code, any tips?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var URLS = []

function get_xml(){
    var XML_FILE = "file:///home/lwm/repos/get-hyped/resources/data.xml"
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: XML_FILE,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            xml_to_data(data);    
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Can't read the XML file!");
        }
      });
}

function xml_to_data(data){
    // get all urls
    $(data).find('links video').each(function() {
        URLS = $(this).find('url').text().split(" ");
    });
}

get_xml();
console.log(URLS.length);
```

Comment: What browser are you using? chrome won't allow an ajax request like this without proper security settings disabled.

Comment: firefox, got over the chrome stuff with a command-line option...is this kind of stuff not possible?

Comment: @KevinB - can you even do a GET request without http directly to a file protocol ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes in browsers that allow it, if your settings are setup correctly, *if the stars align*. definitely not something i would do if it needed to be distributed to users other than myself. I probably wouldn't even do it then. Oh, and i'm assuming this file is also being run from file://, otherwise your are correct, not possible due to same origin policy.

Comment: @KevinB - Yeah, wasn't sure about that one, but I guess it's possible. Protocols must of course match, or it will need CORS headers, but I'm assuming adding proper headers on a file protocol would be hard to do, and it would probably be better to just install a webserver and do this the proper way anyway